# Is this always necessary to use r before path declaration in python

Tags: python, path

I have often seen syntax like this in python code.

```
    import os
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop')
```

I was wondering why would I need to give r before the path, I believe it has something to do with '\' in the path , Is there any other way to give path instead of using r''

Comment: You can escape the `'\'`? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sure that the backslash doesn't escape the characters. It's same as

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop')
```

Comment: That is same as escaping with '\\'. Right ? Is there any other way to do this without using 'r'!

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan why do you not want to use a raw-string literal? It is the most straight-forward way.

Comment: @juanpa I wanted to check if there any other way to do it.

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan Forward slashes

Answer (score 1):

'r' before string literal make Python parse it as a "raw" string, without escaping.
If you want not to use 'r' before string literal, but specify path with single slashes, you can use this notation:

```
"C:/Users/test/Desktop"
```

As it would be in unix-pased systems. Windows understand both "\" and "/" in file paths, so, using "/" give you ability to avoid 'r' letter before the path string.

Also, as it was mentioned, you can specify path with double slashes, but, as I realized, this is not that you wanted:

```
"C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only when it has escape sequences

```
print('C:\sys\cat\Desktop')
```

**Better** to give it as **raw type** to avoid the glitches or using forward slash.

Comment: Have you missed an "r" in your example ?

Comment: @MihanEntalpo It has no escape sequences

Comment: Ok, but this way to write paths is not recommended, because, in this particular case there would be not broblems, but after somebody thoughtlessly changed the path to something like "c:\new\task\runner", everything would break up

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward slashes in Windows as well, so you dont need raw string literals:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat(r'C:\Users\f3k\Desktop\excel.vbs')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=555L, st_atime=1367585162L, st_mtime=1367586148L, st_ctime=1367585162L)
```

Same using forward slashes:

```
>>> os.stat('C:/Users/f3k/Desktop/excel.vbs')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=555L, st_atime=1367585162L, st_mtime=1367586148L, st_ctime=1367585162L)
```

But take care using os.path.join():

```
>>> os.path.join('C:/Users/f3k/Desktop', 'excel.vbs')
'C:/Users/f3k/Desktop\\excel.vbs'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per knowledge, you can use forward slash instead of backward slash and put `r` on it. If you use a backslash then you have to put `r` in front of it or you can do a forward slash if you want to.

Example - >  You can try this in Jupyter notebook:

```
f = open(r'F:\love.txt', 'r')
```

or

```
f = open('F:/love.txt', 'r')
```

Both will work fine.